# Print an order from online shopping

Tags: php, ms-access, printing, e-commerce

I wrote a php shopping cart using a MySQL DB. The shopping part is done, but I can't solve the last part: I have to print the orders that I receive from my website.

I use an A5 format as paper, and I thought to send orders by mail and print it but it's not a scalable solution and it introduces some problems...
Do you know an alternative way to do this?

Also on my server side (in the physical shop) I have a machine with a Microsoft Access instance. I use it to print orders that I receive from phone.. is it possible to make an Access file which contains the order from PHP on my website and then import it into Access?

Comment: Those are two (completely) different questions. I think you'll have more success if you ask one at a time.

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this by creating an A5 PDF with PHP (look up [domPDF](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf) although there are other alternatives).

Once you have your order in PDF format you can easily print it or email it as you wish.